# При попытке запустить Visual Studio 2015 загрузка идет бесконечно (название программы и белый экран)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Если пробовать запустить Visual Studio 2015 загрузка идет бесконечно (название программы и белый экран).

Что делать?

Программа полностью установилась, русская версия.

P.S. у меня windows 8.1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что-то я подозреваю, что версия системы или VS не лицензированая. У меня при работает VS самой последней версии штатно

Answer (score 1):

У многих моих знакомых эта операционная система не позволяет запустить VS 2015. Зато старые версии идут на ура. Либо переустановить Windows, либо версию VS.